# Is it recommended to instantiate new instances of a Python class through a method within the same class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am writing a scraping bot that automates the download of some files. I have created a class and every new article becomes an instance of this `class` to store the data necessary. However, some files automatically download a few others with them and this is determined later on, at a method that belongs to the `File` `class`. What makes sense with the current structure of the code is to instantiate instances for the other files if needed from within the `File` class. I kinda intuitively feel this might be something I might regret later on because of some conflict/problem/bad practice etc... . It  just feels a bit shaky and I can find an alternative way. Is there a problem I don't see? Any documentation that discusses this? Thanks!

**Simplified Code:**

```
class File:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    def collect_file_data(self):
        multiple_files = False
        files_downloaded = self.download_file() # to demonstrate let's say this downloads one or multiple files and returns a list of files downloaded
        if len(files_downloaded) > 1:
            list_of_file_instances = []
            for file in files_downloaded:
                list_of_files_instances.append(File(file))
```

Comment: this is 100% normal. Even the most basic types do this, indeed, for example, all `str` methods return a new instance of `str`, e.g. `"foo bar".replace("foo", "baz")` is a method on the `str` class which internally instantiates a `str` instance and returns it... or `"foo bar baz".split()` is a nother `str` method that returns a list of instances of `str`

Comment: I think you're going to need to be a little more clear about your real scenario to get a good answer here. In the simplified scenario, there seems to be no reason to have it be a method (how would the instance state help you download a file with no other information?). It makes sense to have a method that retrieve's *the* file's data, but the idea of a generalized idea of a file knowing how to do additional, unrelated downloads is... odd.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Returning a modified copy of the instance is normal, or even returning a collection of things derived from the instance (e.g. `str.split`), but it's contextual; it has to make sense *for that class* and *for that method*. The OP's case, where they have an instance representing a file, and for some reason that single file is actually the root of a tree of files, is code smell, even if there's no *general* design principle that says it should always be forbidden. The OP's case seems to be mixing the concept of paths with actual file data, which is indicative of poor design.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I don't disagree with what you are saying. But the fundamental problem is that it isn't clear why *instance state* would be required for a `collect_file_data` method, not that a method returns a collection of objects of the same type, but it's hard to tell without more details.

Comment: @ShadowRanger but, I'm not sure why it being the root of something is code smell. Consider `pathlib.Path("foo").iterdir()`. Again, I don't disagree this is always contextual

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The code smell is mostly in the names in the incomplete skeleton we're given. It seems like sometimes a `File` represents just the metadata (equivalent to `Path`) and sometimes represents the actual data. That's just a guess, based on the name `self.download_file()` (where I suspect that maybe it's supposed to be downloading data), and the thing downloaded being split up to make new `File`s. If it's really that `download_file` is getting a single coherent block of data representing subpaths, like `listdir`, that's fine (aside from `download_file` being a misleading name).